# ROS Arduino Bridge not compiling

Tags: reference, arduino, undefined, ros, bridge

I downloaded the package [ROSArduinoBridge](http://www.ros.org/news/2013/03/new-package-ros-arduino-bridge.html) and the examples that come with the packages don't work in Arduino.

The error I keep getting is:

> ROSArduinoBridge.cpp.o: In function 'runCommand()':
>   /usr/share/arduino/ROSArduinoBridge.ino:150: undefined reference to
>   'readEncoder(int)' /usr/share/arduino/ROSArduinoBridge.ino:179:
>   undefined reference to 'readEncoder(int)'
>   /usr/share/arduino/ROSArduinoBridge.ino:234: undefined reference to
>   'initMotorController()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I'm just confused on why the error is showing up since I haven't changed the code at all.

Comment: More info.
Have you added libraries to project? What code have you tried?

Comment: I added the libraries it said to add, and I've tried all the examples and none of them compiled